# Auto FIll Virtual Wallet for Users Wordpress

Tags: php, paypal, wordpress

I am trying to integrate `Virtual Wallet system` for payments into a WordPress Based E-Commerce Website

I am using this plugin for this  -

[Link To Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-waller-credit-system/)

**Working Process Of This Plugin**

In this plugin From Admin Dashboard Admin can select the user from all users on the website and assigns a particular money in the wallet of the user then user can buy from the website within that money

**My Problem and Requirement**

But for this I need to fill the amount in user's wallet manually . I want that user transfer me money on paypal and it will be automatically added to his wallet

I was unable to find proper information regarding . Is this possible to be done in wordpress and Is there any plugin available to do so

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using PayPal IPN for that.  Every time a transaction hits your PayPal account their server will POST data about the transaction to a URL on your server.  That URL can receive the data and update your system accordingly.  It happens in real-time, too.

You can get up and running with IPN very quickly using the [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) plugin.  Then you could use the hooks provided by the IPN plugin to do whatever you want to do with the PayPal payment data when it receives it.

For example, the paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_payment_status_completed hook would be triggered any time a successful payment occurs, so you could use that within your own plugin or your theme's functions.php file to automatically update the wallet balance of the user based on the data provided in the IPN.

Comment: Is there any way to link the users to the Accounts from where we have received the payment on paypal so that they can be automatically updated to their wallet  Instead of updating manually everytime

Comment: Yes, you would just pass an invoice ID or user ID in the PayPal payment request when it's processed, and then that same ID would come back in the IPN data so you could use it to update your database.